# How to handle multiple layout for each user in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I  handle multiple skins(Layouts) for a user, and user will provide us plain html/css/javascript in Rails 2 ? Please suggest any generic way ?

Comment: Didn't understand. Are you using Rails 2 and need to have one layout per user and let users personalize it?

Comment: @suneel do you have layout that the user can choose from or you want the user to save the layout?

Comment: Let me explain :  There are replicate sites for each user. and user has further clients to access that site. User want to have own choice layout for his site.

Comment: @Mzaragoza I want to user save layout. by uploading html,css, javascript

Comment: can you help us out on what have you tried. some models. or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the layout using a filter like this is on a filter you can change the params with a session or `current_user.layout`

```
layout :choose_layout
def choose_layout    
  if params[:action] == 'index'
    'application'
 elsif params[:action] == 'layout1'
   'layout1'
  end
```